# Ошибка установки Daedalus Wallet на Linux

Tags: linux, криптовалюта

Хочу установить Daedalus Wallet на Linux Mint Tricia.

Написал `chmod +x daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin` и `./daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin`. Вторая команда выдала ошибку: `../run: 1: ../run: ./nix/store/pk5wvyzbzds9wfz33q9fr5bhlf1kqcjb-startup: not found`.

Что делать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А где ты взял бинарник?

Comment: С оф.сайта daedaluswallet.io @don-rumata

Comment: Проблема у тебя в ОС. На моей тестовой чистой бубунте 18.04 всё поставилось ок. https://asciinema.org/a/zC9ndpcNAoUs33s6L4JAQ2oSL

Answer (score 1):

Что собственно произошло? Первое Ваше действие:

```
chmod +x daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin
```

Т.е. Вы сказали ОС, что файл daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin - это **исполнимый** файл. Далее Вы пытаетесь запустить это файл на выполнение:

```
./daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin
```

Судя по "./" в начале имени файла, он лежит у Вас не в корне файловой системы, а в каком-то Вашем каталоге. Программа запускается и выдаёт сообщение об ошибке:

```
/pk5wvyzbzds9wfz33q9fr5bhlf1kqcjb-startup: not found
```

Т.е. Ваша программа *daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin* попросила ОС запустить другую программу -  *pk5wvyzbzds9wfz33q9fr5bhlf1kqcjb-startup* но операционная система не нашла эту программу.

Здесь два существенных момента:

1. Имя *pk5wvyzbzds9wfz33q9fr5bhlf1kqcjb-startup* явно сгенерированное. Скорее всего - это имя "придумала" программа *daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin* в процессе установки и пыталась создать этот файл. Но создать не получилось...
2. Почему не получилось ? Скорее всего потому, что в начале этого имени стоит "/" - т.е. этот файл должен был быть создан в **корне** файловой системы. Подозреваю, у Вашей программы *daedalus-2.1.0-mainnet-14079.bin* не было прав на такое действие.

Ну а первопричина, скорее всего, в настройках путей для инсталляции программы. Почитайте внимательно инструкцию и проверьте пути.

Comment: Я ставил по документации, там хоть из загрузок можно ставить. Видел в сети похожую проблему. Там надо было почистить какой-то хеш, у меня же такого вообще не было -  https://forum.cardano.org/t/installing-daedalus-on-linux/18869

Comment: Нет, не в корне. Файл должен лежать в ./nix/store/

Comment: @bearoforange "Нет, не в корне." - а почему тогда выдаёт "/pk5...." ?

Comment: `./nix/store/pk5wvyzbzds9wfz33q9fr5bhlf1kqcjb-startup`

Comment: @bearoforange Виноват - не увидел из-за переноса строки... :-( Но тогда другой вопрос - а в каталоге ./nix/store/ действительно есть файл pk5wvyzbzds9wfz33q9fr5bhlf1kqcjb-startup ? И он действительно исполнимый ?

Обратите внимание на символ точки в начале пути - там могут быть тонкости...

Comment: Такого каталога вообще нет. Нигде.

Comment: @bearoforange  Вы уверены? Искали с помощью *find* или *locate*? Во время установки распаковываемые файлы могут оказаться в неожиданных местах :-)

Но если этого файла **действительно** нет, значит установщик не смог его создать. Скорее всего - права доступа нарушаются. Проверьте всю иерархию каталогов до того места, где этот файл должен быть создан.

Comment: Ничего не нашёл.